# A software that makes subtitle for a movie?

Tags: windows, gratis, video, video-editing, speech-recognition

I am looking for a software that can make a German subtitle for a German movie.

There is this German TV show Stromberg for which I couldn't find any subtitle. So I want to make its subtitle by myself. Is there any software to do that? I want a software that, first, makes movies' audio to text and, then, make a subtitle of that text for that movie.

Answer (score 1):

I used to translate shows in my native language. By far the easiest one I have found is Subtitle Edit.

https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases

> Subtitle Edit is a free (open source) editor for video subtitles - a
>   subtitle editor :)
>
> With SE you can easily adjust a subtitle if it is out of sync with the
>   video in several different ways. You can also use SE for making new
>   subtitles from scratch (do use the time-line/waveform/spectrogram) or
>   translating subtitles.

The best feature I found was that it displays an audio timeline, which you can use to synchronize your subtitles 100% correctly.

[image]

You can see me using it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNIeaOkdw98